# Why this $C^1$ function is onto?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m $ is class $C^1$

Also $f^{-1}(B)$ is bounded whenever $B$ is bounded

and
 $\nabla f_i(x)$ are linearly independent for each $x$.

Then $f$ is onto.

Why? I have no idea to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

First note that by hypotesis $f$ is a subersion, since the jacobian matrix
\begin{equation}
J_f=\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \nabla f_1 \\
     .\\
.\\
.\\
\nabla f_n
  \end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
has maximum rank at each point, by local subersion theorem this is an open map. If we conclude that it's also a closed map then it's onto, by connectedness. Since $\{y_1,...,y_n,...\}$ is bounded, 
we have $f^{-1}(\{y_1,...,y_n,...\})$ is bounded. Then, $\{x_1,...,x_n,...\}$ is bounded,
so by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem there is a convergent subsequence, $(x_{n_j})_{j\geq1}$ that converges to a point $x_0$, since $f$ is continuous, $lim f(x_{n_j})=f(x_0)$ by
uniqueness of limit we have $f(x_0)=y$ and $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is closed, since it is a nonempty set and $\mathbb{R}^m$ is connected, we have that $f$ is onto.

Comment: note that I used an important fact that n=m, because the hypotesis just give me $n\leq m$ since the $df:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is injective by hypotesis, remember that the matrix that represents $df$ is $J_f$. So, if the result says that f is onto, than it is not possible $n<m$, because in this case Sard's theorem says that $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ has measure zero. So, $m=n$.

Comment: I think you are using circular logic for $n=m$. I think $n \leq m$ is sufficient to state your answer.